# Is it okay to pass null values as a path variable to a REST Controller?

Tags: java, rest, parameters, controller, null

I have a RestController. I have an endpoint on the controller. Is okay to pass null values to the endpoint and controller?

As an example:

```
 @RestController
 @RestMapping("/some")
 public class SomeController {  

  @GetMapping(value = "/thing/{someid}/{bid})
  public @ResponseBody 
  ResponseEntity<String>  
  getSomething(@PathVariable("someid" String someid, 
               @PathVariable("bid" String bid ) {
       ...
   }


}
```

Can I call this REST controller endpoint with a null value for someid or bid? It doesn't seem too clean. Is there other way to do this?

Edited: 
I just updated the example to pass in 2 parameters instead of just 1.

Edit 2:
Is it okay to make a call as /some/thing/null/null ?

Comment: You can think of making the path variable as optional , cant you?

Comment: What do you mean by "null values"? Are you calling it like `/some/thing/null` or `/some/thing/`? (The second is not possible.)

Comment: Even if you didn't enter any someid, you don't get any error, rather you will get 404 not found because URL you are requesting is not available in your backend.

Comment: I just edited the example to pass in two parameters

Comment: if someid has a value, and I don't have a value for bid, then the user will get a 404. If the user sets bid to null then they won't get a 404. It just doesn't seem "clean" to have the user send in a null as a parameter.

Comment: Is it okay to pass in a call like /some/thing/null/null ?